# This organization's certificate has been revoked. IE 11

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-9, selenium-grid

This organization's certificate has been revoked.

Security certificate problems may indicate an attempt to fool you or intercept any data you send to the server.

I try to fix this issue through Tools --->Internet options--->advanced ----->Under security click check certification revoked and publisher check box but still browser is not been responding the changes getting same problem

Did anyone has come across the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your problem here, but you may want to try re-starting your Hub and Nodes with `-trustAllSSLCertificates` switch turned on. As the documentation says it "Forces the Selenium proxy to trust all SSL certificates.  This doesn't work in browsers that don't use the Selenium proxy."

e.g.

`java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar -trustAllSSLCertificates true -role hub`